# Create a random string, check against table, if already exists, create new and try again, if it doesn't, insert - script not working?

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do, is create a random string, check it against a table, if it already exists, create a new random string and try again, if it doesn't insert it into said table.

My script is based on a script that I was given yesterday, it's all working as planned aside from `if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)`, which will automatically return false and execute the else statement. I've tried to change the value to 1 instead of 0, which executes the if statement, regardless of whether it's true or false (e.g. I swap out `$authcode = dechex($num1).$dechex($num2);` for a string such as `$authcode ="eey7y764";` which doesn't exist in the table, yet it still executes the if statement).

Here's my script:

```
function authCode() {

$num1 = mt_rand(1, 2147483647);
$num2 = mt_rand(1, 2147483647); 
$authcode = dechex($num1).dechex($num2);

include("../db/71cfde725dc86.php");

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_uname, $db_pword) or die("Couldn't connect because ".mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($db_name);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE valcode='$authcode'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SELECT query failed due to ".mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    $authCode = authCode();
}
else 
{
$query2 = "INSERT INTO records (valcode) VALUES ('$authcode')";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("INSERT query failed due to ".mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($conn);

return $authcode;
}

authCode();
```

Could you please tell me what changes need to be made to have it function as I'd like?

Any comments or advice will be greatly appreciated :)!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to compare the number of rows.  It's always 1, because you're selecting `COUNT(*)`.  It will always give you a single number (hopefully 0 or 1).  You have to compare 0 and 1 to the VALUE of that number, not how many of that number there are (which will always be 1).

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row['COUNT(*)']==1) ...
```

Also, you don't want to recursively call `authCode()`, not like that.  You'll possibly make a big stack of open DB connections (not to mention that they'll be opened and closed quickly, which is expensive).  You'll probably want to pass along the connection.

```
function authCode($conn){
    ...
    $authCode = authCode($conn);
}
$conn = mysql_connect( ... );
authCode($conn);
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: So, I should change `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` to just `SELECT FROM`?, or are you saying I need to use an entirely different comparison function?

Comment: What functions could I use to pass along the connection? Couldn't I just close the concection before authCode(); is called, and then, re-connect in the `else` statement?